# Primes $p$ for which $p-1$ has a large prime factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

What are the best known density results and conjectures for primes $p$ where $p-1$ has a large prime factor $q$, where by "large" I mean something greater than $\sqrt{p}$.

The most extreme case is that of a safe prime ([Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime)), which is a prime $p$ such that $(p - 1)/2$ is also a prime (the smaller prime is called a Sophie Germain prime). I believe it is conjectured (and not yet proved) that infinitely many safe primes exist, and that the density is roughly $c/\log^2 n$ for some constant $c$ (as it should be from a probabilistic model).

For the more general setting, where we are interested in the density of primes $p$ for which $p-1$ has a large prime factor, the only general approach I am aware of is the [prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#The_prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions), and some of its strengthenings such as the [Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri-Vinogradov_theorem) (conditional to the GRH), the (still open) [Elliott-Halberstam conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott-Halberstam_conjecture), Chowla's conjecture on the first Dirichlet prime, and some partial results related to this conjecture. All of these deal with the existence of primes $p \equiv a \pmod q$ for arbitrary $q$ and arbitrary $a$ that is coprime to $q$.

My question: can we expect qualitatively better results for the situation where $q$ is prime and $a = 1$? Also, I am not interested in specifying $q$ beforehand, so the existence of a $p$ such that there exists *any* large prime $q$ dividing $p-1$ would be great. References to existing conjectures, conditional results, and unconditional results would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

See "[On the number of primes $p$ for which $p+a$ has a large prime factor](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0025579300004575)." (Goldfeld, Mathematika 16 1969 23--27.) Using Bombieri-Vinogradov he proves, for a fixed integer $a$, that

$$\sum_{p \leq x} \sum_{\substack{ x^{1/2}< q \leq x  \\ q | p+a}} \ln q = \frac{x}{2} + O\left(\frac{x \ln \ln x}{ \ln x} \right)$$

where the summation is over $p$ and $q$ prime. Note that this implies that the number of primes $p$ less than $x$ such that $p-1$ has a prime factor greater than $p^{1/2}$ is asymptotically at least $\frac{x}{2\ln x}$.

Comment: Strange - the density of integers $n$ that have a prime factor greater than $n^{1/2}$ is $\log 2$ by results on friable (or smooth) numbers (see the Dickman rho function). I would think that the density of such shifted primes is also $\log 2$. I have proved this subject to a version of the Hardy-Littlewood prime tuples conjecture (see my J. Number Th. paper of 2002).

Comment: Mark, your conclusion that the number of primes less than x such that p-1 has a prime factor larger than $\sqrt(p)$ is asymptotic to x/(2ln(x)) is not correct. Note that we have a log(q) factor in the result not log(p) and for the relevant range of q we have $\log(p)/2 \leq \log(q) \leq \log(p)$ and they are not asymptotically equal. Greg is correct that the density should be $\log 2$.


Comment: Johan, thanks! I've adjusted the text.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that sieve methods (in particular methods similar to Chen's result on "almost" Goldbach and twin primes) should give infinitely primes $p$ such $(p-1)/2$ is a product of two primes. That's more than what you asked.

Wikipedia quotes a result of Bombieri-Friedlander-Iwaniec stating that Linnik's constant is $2$ for almost all moduli. If the same is true for infinitely many prime moduli $q$, then you are in business. A prime $p \equiv 1 \mod q, p \ll q^2$ is what you want.

Maybe an analytic number theorist will come along and give precise references.

[Wikipedia - Sieve Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_methods)

[Wikipedia - Linnik's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 5):

Fouvry showed that the relative density is positive of primes $p$ for which the largest prime factor of $p+a$ is $\ge p^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \approx .6687$.

Etienne Fouvry, Théorème de Brun-Titchmarsh: application au théorème de Fermat, Invent. Math 79 (1985), 383–407. MR0778134 (86g:11052)

Comment: I didn't understand. Did you leave the statement incomplete? What is the conclusion about the relative density?

Comment: ..."is positive"?

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha \le 0.6687$ above instead of $\alpha > 0.6687$? The larger the $\alpha$, the smaller the density, and the paper you've quoted also seems to suggest that.

Comment: @Vipul: I'm sure that I mean $\alpha > 0.6687$ since we're interested in $p-1$ have a *large* prime factor.

Comment: No, think carefully - it must be $\alpha < 0.6687$.  That's what the math review says, too.

Comment: @DavidHansen:  perhaps I didn't state it clearly enough.  Fouvry showed that there is an $\alpha$ which is approximately 0.6687 so that for a fixed $a \ne 0$ the set `$\{p \text{ prime}: P(p+a) \ge p^{\alpha} \}$` has positive density in the set of all primes, where $P(n)$ denotes the larges prime factor dividing $n$.  Bigger values of $\alpha$ are better.  The post alluding to a result of Goldfeld had $\alpha = \frac 12$.

Answer (score 4):

John A. Gordon introduced the notion of *strong primes* (try Wikipedia) which, beside other requirements, are primes $p$ satisfying $p \equiv 1 \mod r$ for some large prime $r$ of about the same size as $p$. In the following paper, it has been shown how to construct strong primes of arbitrary bit size efficiently and with high probability:

- John A. Gordon: ["Strong Primes Are Easy to Find"](http://link.springer.de/link/service/series/0558/bibs/0209/02090216.htm), Proceedings of EUROCRYPT '84, LNCS 209, Springer, 1985.