# Density of primes $p$ where $p-1$ has a prime factor exceeding $p^{2/3}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Fouvry proved* that primes $p$ such that the greatest prime factor, $q$, of $p-1$ is greater than $p^{2/3}$ have positive density in the primes. (The sequence is [A073024](https://oeis.org/A073024) in the OEIS.)

Are there any results on what this density might be? Numerical calculations (a simple factorization sieve) don't seem to be converging:

| Size | Density |
| --- | --- |
| 10<sup>3</sup> | 4.80% |
| 10<sup>4</sup> | 3.83% |
| 10<sup>5</sup> | 3.22% |
| 10<sup>6</sup> | 2.74% |
| 10<sup>7</sup> | 2.39% |
| 10<sup>8</sup> | 2.10% |
| 10<sup>9</sup> | 1.89% |

Heuristically, Aitken extrapolation suggests perhaps 1% is reasonable.

* Fouvry's proof is actually stronger, allowing one to obtain $\approx 0.6687$. Perhaps others have since improved this constant. I am proximately interested in the exponent $2/3$ but results for any larger exponent are also welcome.

Etienne Fouvry, Théorème de Brun-Titchmarsh: application au théorème de Fermat, Invent. Math 79 (1985), pp. 383-407.

Related: [Primes $p$ for which $p−1$ has a large prime factor](https://mathoverflow.net/q/14796/6043)

Comment: What's density of natural numbers $n$ with a prime factor greater than $n^{2/3}$? Something involving dickman function. Maybe same answer to your question?

Comment: Of the 168 primes up to 1000, 48 satisfy the condition, which is two sevenths of them. It's 4.80% of all the numbers up to 1000, but that's not what Fouvry is talking about. Two sevenths fits much better with Gorodetsky's reply.

Comment: @DaveBenson That's... a really dumb error I've made. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a standard conjecture that this density is $1-\rho(3/2)=\log(3/2) \approx 0.405$. Here $\rho$ is the Dickman function (as hinted by mathworker21).

*Details*: Let $\pi(x,y)=\#\{ p \le x: p-1 \in S(y)\}$ where $S(y) = \{ n : p \mid n \implies p \le y\}$ is the set of $y$-smooth numbers. In equation (5.1) of Granville's survey "Smooth numbers: computational number theory and beyond" the relation $$(\star)\quad \pi(x,y) \sim \pi(x) \rho(u)$$ is conjectured, where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes up to $x$, $u$ is $\log x/\log y$, the limit that is taken is $x \to \infty$ and $y$ is allowed to vary as long as $u$ is bounded away from $1$ and $\infty$: $1\ll u-1 \ll 1$. It is remarked that this conjecture follows from the Elliott-Halberstam conjecture. See the references in section 5.3 of Granville's survey for more on $(\star)$. Next let
$$T(x)=\#\{ p \le x: p-1 \text{ has a prime factor exceeding }p^{2/3}\}.$$
Since $\pi(x)-\pi(x,y)$ counts primes $p \le x$ such that $p-1$ has a prime factor exceeding $y$, we have $$\pi(x)-\pi(x,x^{2/3}) \le T(x),$$ implying that $$\liminf T(x)/\pi(x) \ge 1-\rho(3/2)\quad\text{assuming $(\star)$.}$$ For every fixed $c \in (0,1)$, we have $$\pi(x)-\pi(x,(cx)^{2/3}) - (\pi(cx)-\pi(cx,(cx)^{2/3})) \ge T(x)-T(cx),$$ which implies that $$\limsup (T(x)-T(cx))/\pi(x) \le (1-c)(1-\rho(3/2))\quad\text{ assuming $(\star)$.}$$By noticing $T(cx)/\pi(x) \le \pi(cx)/\pi(x)= c+o(1)$ and taking $c \to 0^+$ it follows that
$$\limsup T(x)/\pi(x) \le  1-\rho(3/2)\quad\text{ assuming $(\star)$.}$$
In conclusion, $(\star)$ implies that $$T(x) \sim \pi(x) (1-\rho(3/2)).$$